# How to get a cmd input and sending it with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I made a program where a Discord client is run in CMD and has now hit a roadblock. So I wanted to send messages from CMD, but doing so would either make the inputs not work or the bot not work.

Main:

```
import discord
import messages
import sndmessage as snd
warningz = '\nI, the user will not use this program for any harmful attempts.'
bot = discord.Client()

def check(qw):
    if qw.lower() == 'n':
        quit()

print(warningz)
yousure = input('\nDo you agree to this simple sentence? Y/N: ')
check(yousure)

token = input('Please enter token: ')
name = input('Input username: ')
channel = input('Set default channel: ')
# start services
print('Starting...')
messages.channelid = channel
def getinput():
    while True:
        a = input()
        snd.sendmsg(a)

messages.run(token)
```

Message reciever (messages module):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks
import sndmessage
import logging
import datetime

bot = discord.Client()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
channelid = 0

async def activate():
    sndmessage.channelid = channelid

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    ww = datetime.datetime.now()
    if msg.author != bot.user:
        auth = msg.author
        msg = msg.content
        print(str(auth)+' ['+str(ww)+']',msg)
def run(a):
    """Runs the bot with the token given by the user."""
    bot.run(a)
```

Message sender (i thought it would be useful idk) sndmessage module

```
import discord
import logging
import datetime

bot = discord.Client()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
channelid = 0

@bot.event
async def sendmsg(a):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channelid)
    await channel.send(a)

if __name__ = '__main__' #not done here yet i think its useful but its just an opinion
def run(a):
    """Runs the bot with the token given by the user."""
    bot.run(a)
```

I also do need to improve this so can you guys also give tips and reviews on this. Thanks!

### edit

New and improved code with a much more confusing error for me.

Main:

```
import discord
import datetime
import logging
import time
import send
import threading
import io
from termcolor import colored,cprint
warningz = '\nI, the user will not use this program for any harmful attempts.'
bot = discord.Client()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
inputthread = threading.Thread(target=send.startloop)
channelid = 0
active = 0 


# services
class properties:
    active = 0 # not useful, will get deleted sometime in the future

@bot.event
async def reciever():
    latest = io.open('msgcontainer.txt','+r')
    a = latest.read()
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(channelid))
    channel.send(a)
    latest.flush()
    print('success')
recieverthread = threading.Thread(target=reciever)

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    ww = datetime.datetime.now()
    if msg.author != bot.user:
        auth = msg.author
        msg = msg.content
        print(colored(str(auth),'cyan')+' ['+colored(str(ww),'yellow')+'] ',msg)

def check(qw):
    if qw.lower() == 'n':
        quit()
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cprint('Login successful!','green')
    print('Please give the functions 10 seconds to start')
    time.sleep(10)
    recieverthread.start()
    inputthread.start()
print(warningz)
yousure = input('\nDo you agree to this simple sentence? Y/N: ')
check(yousure)

#token = input('Please enter token: ')
#name = input('Input username: ')
#channel = input('Set default channel: ')
channelid = 0000000000000 #please replace with channel in final product
# start bot
try:
    bot.run('theamonglicode') #replace with token
except:
    print('You passed an improper token.')
```

error while prototyping:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (startloop):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python-Program\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python-Program\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Terminality\send.py", line 7, in startloop
    msg = input()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Terminality\main.py", line 29, in msginput
    defchannel.send(latest.read())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

above was an attempt to send a message thru `defchannel = bot.get_channel(channelid)`.

next attempt didnt send anything nor made an error.

third attempt is the improved main code, made error:

```
D:\Python-Program\lib\threading.py:953: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'reciever' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

### edit 2

the code that's causing the problem

```
import discord
import io
import sys
import threading
import send
channelid = 000000000000000000
bot = discord.Client()
def reciever(event,args):
    if event == 'builtins.input':
        latest = io.open('msgcontainer.txt','+r')
        a = latest.read()
        channel = bot.get_channel(int(channelid))
        channel.send(a)
        latest.flush()
        print('success')
loop =threading.Thread(target=startloop)
loop.start()
sys.addaudithook(reciever)
bot.run('apple')
```

i made it to be able to run by its own

Comment: I guess it should be `bot.run(token)` and not `messages.run(token)`. Also, I don't think you need 3 files for this. And you're creating many `Client`s by using `bot = discord.Client()` in every file.

Comment: `run()` has to work all time - and this is blocking other code. If you want to use `input()` (which also blocks code) then you should run it in separated thread.

Comment: `input` is blocking, and unfortunately, you can't do anything about it. You could try multithreading and reading the input off another thread.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I have shortened the code to be more smaller and now is run with 1 client, not 3 anymore

Comment: @TerminalVelocity, I think the error asks you to add `await` before all the lines inside the `reciever()` function (as it's `async`). Try adding `await` line by line as all lines may not need to be `await`ed. Try first with `channel.send(a)`. Please [edit] your post again to include the full code (a [mre]) where `defchannel = bot.get_channel(channelid)` is. Are you trying to send something to a channel the user inputs? Or it most probably is because `channelid`  is `0`, so `defchannel = bot.get_channel(channelid)` doesn't get a valid channel, and gives the `AttributeError`.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder The code is at edit 2

Comment: @TerminalVelocity, I may not be able to help you out with multi-threading, but try `print`ing `channel`, `channelid` and `int(channelid)`. I guess Python converts the `000...` to `0` and then to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send TOS confirmation to your discord you should just use webhooks. implementing bots into enduser products isnt a good idea cause people **will** get the token.